# No such container (using worker_harness_container_image)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam Job on Google Cloud Dataflow (Job-ID: `2020-06-08_23_39_43-14062032727466654144`) using the flags

```
--experiment=beam_fn_api 
--worker_harness_container_image=gcr.io/PROJECT_NAME/apachebeamp3.7_imageconversion:latest
```

Unfortunately, the job ist stuck in the starting state. The job with the exact same configuration ran in the beginning of this year (February?) and I'm wondering what has changed since and what changes are needed on my side to get it running again.

If I run the job locally with

```
--runner=PortableRunner \
--job_endpoint=embed \
--environment_config=PROJECT_NAME/apachebeamp3.7_imageconversion:latest
```

it runs perfectly.

In the Dataflow logs, i see the following error messages:

```
getPodContainerStatuses for pod "dataflow-beamapp-sam-0609063936-65-06082339-h464-harness-zzpb_default(a65b24a783afd25920bf29ff27d7baf8)" failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: 586554fec1cf2942c7d2f45589db02b217c90c2ea96982041fc3f12b4b6595ff"
```

and

```
ContainerStatus "1647b951d266b4b1d318317b1836002eb4731a510dffa38ba6b58b45a7710784" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: 1647b951d266b4b1d318317b1836002eb4731a510dffa38ba6b58b45a7710784
```

I'm a bit puzzled regarding the container ID since `gcr.io/PROJECT_NAME/apachebeamp3.7_imageconversion:latest` has currently `8bdf43f9cdcd20d4c258a7810c81cb5214ecc984e534117ef8ba1a4cab2a3dae`.

Questions:

- Why do I get error messages related to containers that seem not to be
  referenced by me?
- What do I need to do in order to get my job running again?

**Edit** Additional information based on question below:

Thanks for the pointers. I have looked at the `dataflow.googleapis.com/kubelet` logs. The only errors I see there are

- `while getting AWS credentials NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.`
- `ContainerStatus "55271a8a1af2a90d6162eda03bd8924aad502fd32f09ca50bf35af58e428cf59" from runtime service failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: No such container: 55271a8a1af2a90d6162eda03bd8924aad502fd32f09ca50bf35af58e428cf59`
- `Error syncing pod a65b24a783afd25920bf29ff27d7baf8 ("dataflow-beamapp-sam-0609063936-65-06082339-h464-harness-7056_default(a65b24a783afd25920bf29ff27d7baf8)"), skipping: [failed to "StartContainer" for "sdk0" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=sdk0 pod=dataflow-beamapp-sam-0609063936-65-06082339-h464-harness-7056_default(a65b24a783afd25920bf29ff27d7baf8)"`.

Strangely, I do not see a category `worker-startup` in the log viewer. What do I need to do to see those log entries and to be able to make the next step on this debugging journey :-)?

Comment: Could you please share the information which Dataflow SDK version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python with `apache_beam = {extras = ["gcp"],version = "==2.22.0"}`. Docker container is based on `apachebeam/python3.7_sdk:latest`.

Comment: It's hard to say what is happening without seeing worker startup logs.  Dataflow customer support would be in a better position to help. To debug this yourself, I would try to start a job passing the same container without customization and then incrementally add your customizations to understand when the breakage happens. Also take a look at "kubelet" and "worker-startup" logs to see if there is anything unusual. Finally, you could try SSHing to the VM and docker pull the container from your repository to see if it's a permission issue.

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I made multiple mistakes:

- In my Dockerfile, I needed to change `FROM apachebeam/python3.7_sdk:latest` to `FROM apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:latest`. According to https://hub.docker.com/r/apachebeam/python3.7_sdk, there has been a switch from version 2.20.0 onwards.
- My Dockerfile didn't use the correct version of the Python beam package.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue, getting `Container Status xxxxx service failed` and `Error Syncing pod`

I am trying to read data from the file and process it for a streaming application. Once I removed `options.setStreaming(true)` it is working properly.

Streaming is for unbounded data like reading from PubSub, Kafka and batching is for bounded data reading from database or file.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was fixed when I removed the option `--experiments=use_runner_v2` when running the pipeline

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).